# Get a key with wait timer batch

Tags: batch-file

Hello I want to get a key and if not key is press in a certain amount of time return nothing. I don't people to have to press enter to do it. So no `set /p` since that waits for an enter. Any ideas?

Comment: You're looking for the `choice` command. Type `choice /?` for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `choice`. You can't differ capitals or get `!@#$%^&*(` etc.

```
choice /c:0abcdefghijklnmopqrstuvwxyz /t:"INSERT SECONDS TO WAIT" /d:0 >NUL
```

the `abc` is the characters we can enter and the `"INSERT" SECONDS TO WAIT"` is how many seconds you want to wait. The /d is for default `0`. The >NUL is so no there is no output. Use this to get the result:

```
set result=%errorlevel%
```

or

```
set result=!errorlevel!
```

The result will be the letter press but in it's order. So `a` is `2` since it's second in order.

Comment: The `/cs` flag lets you differentiate between uppercase and lowercase letters.

Comment: I've been looking for this for quite the while, hats off to you sir.